# Kik search engine not picking up mobile app even though robots.txt is empty

Tags: kik

Kik's search engine is not picking up our HTML5 mobile app even though our robots.txt file is empty.

Our mobile app is at http://panabee-games.herokuapp.com/spoof/spoof.

Our robots.txt file is at http://panabee-games.herokuapp.com/robots.txt.

Did this happen to others?

Please note: we were asked by Kik customer support to post this question here.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes please? We were asked by Kik customer support to post the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kik indexing service determines listing eligibility based on 3 things:

- kik.js is included
- all necessary tags are included (description meta, icon link)
- robots.txt doesn't allow indexing

This is the rule I would recommend using:

```
User-agent: KikBot
Disallow:

# Other rules if needed
# User-agent:*
# Disallow: /
```

I would also recommend putting your `kik.js` script at the bottom of the `body`. Other than that your code looks good.

Also, keep in mind that once your app is indexed it is added to the whitelist queue that is checked by a representative at Kik. They very quickly verify that the app does not contain any inappropriate content and then add it to the list of searchable apps.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Shouldn't an empty robots.txt achieve the same thing?

Comment: It should be resolved now. My apologies about the delay.